# Mousedown Event with ipad/iphone Compatibility? - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wrote a small scroller in jquery. The scroller seems to work perfectly on PC and Macs. However it doesn't work on touch devices.

I guess this is due to `mousedown` property being called. how do I make this work on both PC and touch screen devices?

Thanks

```
$('.scroll-nav-up, .scroll-nav-down').live('click', function(){
    $('.scroller-wrap').stop();
    return false;
});


$('.scroll-nav-up').live('mousedown', function(){

    $(this).closest('.item').find('.scroller-wrap').animate({
        top: -($(this).closest('.item').find('.scroller-wrap').height() - 250)
    }, 800);

});


$('.scroll-nav-down').live('mousedown', function(){

    $(this).closest('.item').find('.scroller-wrap').animate({
        top: 0
    }, 800);

});
```

Comment: To get an answer with code fixes - publish a demo and link to it in the question so that people can test what works and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special found, so at this moment I am using 2 scripts. The first script identifies the the touch screen devices as written by Alastair Campbell on [Detecting touch-based browsing](http://alastairc.ac/2010/03/detecting-touch-based-browsing/).

```
function isTouchDevice() {
   var el = document.createElement('div');
   el.setAttribute('ongesturestart', 'return;');
   if(typeof el.ongesturestart == "function"){
      return true;
   }else {
      return false
   }
}
```

and then use the `mousedown` event for regular browsers and use `tap` event for touch screen devices.

P.S - Using both jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery mobile try handling its new events `tap` and `taphold`

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html

I can't test it, so it's just an idea (I'm not sure if I understand what your app does), but you can try and change click to mouseup event.