# Making jquery slider work on touch devices

Tags: jquery, user-interface, touch, screen

I have made a page using jquery ui and am aware that it cannot support touch devices by default.  You can find it [here](http://training.mercury.stellarbluewebdesign.com/GainOil/)! I am trying to make it so the sliders move on touch screen devices.  Please don't answer this question with "use touch punch" as I am aware of its existence, but cannot figure out how to use it.  The Js that it is using can be found under the js/functions.js link at the top of the page.  Thank You

Comment: The link to touch punch on that demo page is 404.

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448895/mousedown-event-with-ipad-iphone-compatibility-jquery-mobile

Comment: It just takes me to your stack overflow home page

Comment: check http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html

Comment: While I appreciate all the links, they aren't doing me any good.  This was not written in jquery mobile and I don't know how to make that work with jquery ui so unless you can explain how to do that it doesn't do me any good.  thanks though

Comment: I was just saying that you get touch punch loaded, and it should just start working. You don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Am I missing something that loads it? I don't get how to load it.

Comment: Solved... just add this to the head of your document. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> and everything will work fine.  While I appreciate everyone's help I'd just like to say that the documentation for this could be MUCH better in specifying the exact location of the files. Thanks everyone.